Next.js next/image 'image' implicity has an 'any' type - how to fix?
I am new to Next.js and TypeScript and cant seem to find any resources on how to fix this issue:
import Image from 'next/image';

export default function Item({ image }) { // <-- parameter image needs a 'type' definition?
  ...
}

but the above gives this notice/warning/error with regard to the parameter image:
Binding element 'image' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031). (parameter) image: any
Sample usage of image:
<Image src={image} alt={title} fill />

I understand that  TS needs variable types to be defined/declared but I sure as heck have no idea what 'type' NextJS Image should be and I also know that giving it the any type is not the way to go either? How can I fix this issue?
I tried the following but doesn't work:
export default function Item({ image: Image }) { // <-- tried the `image: Image` syntax

Does anyone have any resource, documentation, or preferred place to search up what the right type would be for a parameter/function and the right syntax that  goes along with it to quell these warnings?
Thanks in advance.

Update your question to include where do you use image

What is next/image? A module or a file of mime-type image/*?

by default in typescript if you don't specify the type of a variable,  it will be implicitly typed by element affect inside
It if it's an object by default the implicit type will be any
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html
but you have the warning due to noImplicitAny which is true by default in tsconfig
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#noImplicitAny
you have to explicitly define the type of your parameter or if you truly want any specify it
export default function Item({ image }: {image: Image}) 

just be careful in your case the type affected should have image property inside it to be valid
if Image object contain the path of the image you will have the following
export default function Item({ image }: {image: string}) 


I tried your suggestiion and that  in turn gives another error:
code:
export default function Item({ image }: {image: Image}) ...
error:
'Image' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Image'?ts(2749) type Image = /*unresolved*/ any

what is present inside the imported element Image ? it's a type or directly the path to the image ? if it's a string in that case the code became export default function Item({ image }: {image: string})

thanks, it gets passed to:
<Image src={image} alt={title} fill />
so i believe it is string so I changed to image: string - so Image in itself has no type? i guess that    is why im confused

great if you found the solution, yes it's that ;) i update my reply in consequences may i ask you to mark it if it close the topic ?
